# Prove an equality for the definition of operator norm

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

Consider a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ prove that:
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in S^{n-1}}\|Ax\|_2=\max_{x\in S^{n-1}, y\in S^{m-1}}\langle Ax,y\rangle
\end{equation}

MY ATTEMPT

$(\leq)$
Recall that if we set $y=\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|_2}$ we have that $y\in S^{m-1}$; then:
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in S^{n-1}, y\in S^{m-1}}\langle Ax,y\rangle\geq\max_{x\in S^{n-1}}\langle Ax,\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|_2}\rangle =\max_{x\in S^n-1}\frac{\|Ax\|_2^2}{\|Ax\|_2}=\max_{x\in S^n-1}\|Ax\|_2
\end{equation}

Can someone give me an hint to verify the opposite inequalitY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^{n-1}$ being compact and $x\rightarrow\|Ax\|_{2}$ is a continuous map, so it attains the max, say,
\begin{align*}
\max_{x\in S^{n-1}}\|Ax\|_{2}=\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}
\end{align*}
for some $x_{0}\in S^{n-1}$. If $\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}=0$ the result holds immediately. Now we set $y_{0}=Ax_{0}/\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}$, then $y_{0}\in S^{n-1}$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}=\sqrt{\left<Ax_{0},Ax_{0}\right>}=\sqrt{\left<Ax_{0},y_{0}\right>}\sqrt{\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}},
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\|Ax_{0}\|_{2}=\left<Ax_{0},y_{0}\right>\leq\max_{x,y\in S^{n-1}}\left<Ax,y\right>.
\end{align*}

For the other side, we apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so
\begin{align*}
\left<Ax,y\right>\leq\left|\left<Ax,y\right>\right|\leq\|Ax\|_{2}\|y\|_{2},
\end{align*}
when $y\in S^{n-1}$, then $\|y\|_{2}=1$, the rest is clear then.

Comment: Thanks, is my computation for the first inequality fine?

Comment: It goes through as well.